# Parametrising the boundary of an open ball

Tags: complex-analysis, line-integrals

I have been asked to evaluate line integrals of complex functions, namely of the form $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz$$ where $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function and $\gamma : [t_{0}, t_{1}] \rightarrow U$ is a curve. and to do this we need to parametrise the curve $\gamma$. So my question is how exactly would we parametrise the boundary of an open ball $B_{r}(a)$?

Comment: The ball is in this case a disk, and the boundary of a disk is a circle. Have you a faint recollection how one could parametrise a circle?

Comment: is it just $r.e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta:[0, 2\pi]$

Comment: Pretty much. Only the centre of our disk is $a$, not $0$, so we need a translation, $a + re^{i\theta}$.